# How can I expand a inequality with Abs

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

I want

```
Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1
```

to be convert to

```
x + y <= 1 && x + y >= -1 && x - y <= 1 && x - y >= -1
```

How could I get it with Mathematica?

Comment: `Reduce[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}, Reals]` already does a pretty good job--and incidentally shows that all solutions lie in the interval $[-1,1]$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
expandAbs[eq_] := And @@ Flatten@Module[{case},
eq //. 
 x_?((case = Cases[#, Abs[_], Infinity, 1]) =!= {} &) :> (case = 
    First[case]; {x /. case -> First[case], 
    x /. case -> -First[case]})]
expandAbs[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1]
```

Comment: This isn't always algebraically correct, but this is: `expandAbs[eq_] := 
 Module[{case}, 
  eq //. x_?((case = 
          Cases[#, Abs[_], Infinity, 1]) =!= {} &) :> (case = 
      First[case]; 
     Or[(x /. case -> First[case]) && 
       First@case >= 0, (x /. case -> -First[case]) && 
       First@case < 0])]`

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to visualize the answer:

```
RegionPlot[Evaluate@Reduce[Abs[x] + Abs[y] <= 1, {x, y}, Reals], {x,-2,2}, {y,-2,2}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Abs[x] + Abs[y] //. (k_: 1) Abs[x_] + y_ :> {k x + y, -k x + y} /.
 t_ :> And @@ Thread[Flatten[t] <= 1]
```

> x + y <= 1 && x - y <= 1 && -x + y <= 1 && -x - y <= 1

```
Abs[x] + 2 Abs[y] + 3 Abs[z] //. (k_: 1) Abs[x_] + y_ :> {k x + y, -k x + y} /.
 t_ :> And @@ Thread[Flatten[t] <= 1]
```

> x + 2 y + 3 z <= 1 && x + 2 y - 3 z <= 1 && x - 2 y + 3 z <= 1 && 
>    x - 2 y - 3 z <= 1 && -x + 2 y + 3 z <= 1 && -x + 2 y - 3 z <= 
>     1 && -x - 2 y + 3 z <= 1 && -x - 2 y - 3 z <= 1